# QBSDK Distribution for VB6 App

Tags: vb6, inno-setup, quickbooks, qbfc

Ok, I went through great lengths but I finally got my integration to quickbooks working on my VB6 application.  It works perfectly on my build machine.  I actually installed the qbdsk11 on my build machine and worte and tested the code.  The ONLY new reference in the project is the QBFC11.dll.

So, I added the QBFC11.dll to my innosetup, told it to do a regsvr on the dll, and hoped this was enough.

NOT.

First, during install, I get a failure to register the dll.  Apparently, this DLL isnt meant to be registered?

But the .DLL was put in Windows System32, so I tried my program anyways...

NOPE.  Doesnt work.  I get a runtime 91, about an object variable not set. Which makes sense, if it cant create the object.

So, for grins, I moved a copy of the .DLL into the program folder, next to my executable.

Same thing.  Runtime error 91.

So, i then grab the whole qbsdk11 installer and install it on this machine.  I figure I can make it an additional download for people who want to use this extra functionality.

But no, even with the whole SDK installed, I still get the same runtime error.

I have not been able to find any CLEAR information on how to proceed.  I'd prefer for this to be part of my base install.  But apparently something still just isn't right.

What did I miss? How do I fix this?  I don't even know what to try next.

Comment: Have you asked QucikBooks? They should have included a distribution guide listing what files need to be put where and what done with them. Do you knwo what line it's actually failing on?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using QBFC11, you must install the QBFC11 redistributable components with your application. You can find instructions on how to do this in the [QBSDK Programmer's Guide](https://member.developer.intuit.com/qbSDK-Current/doc/html/wwhelp/wwhimpl/js/html/wwhelp.htm) in the section titled *Redistributing SDK Components With Your Application*, subsection *Using Installers and Merge Modules*.

The most likely cause of the runtime error you're currently getting is the manipulation of the QBFC11.DLL that you did before you installed the SDK. I would start again with a clean OS image so that you can get the proper procedure down.